# Problems rendering hair in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I'm currently modeling a Red Panda for animation I am doing and I am having trouble rendering the hair. My model looks like this-
[image: Original Panda]

The render looks like this-
[image]

These are my nodes:

[image]

And here are the particle settings-

[image]
[image]
[image]

What do I do? 
I've only been using blender for a few months so most things are new to me because I am only 14 years old. All answers are much appreciated. My intentions for this is to make a continuous flowing fur on the Red Panda in order to produce a seamless effect when animating and rendering the final product. I do not want a spotty fur coat with missing patches. After rendering, the object mode view of the panda is all messed up and the hair is sticking up in all different directions (see below) instead of the way I had it combed. When I press undo (Ctrl+Z) it goes back to the way I had it before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We do not see the same size of your panda...but I believe both are the same, am I right ?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you spend a few word describing what exactly don't satisfy you at the moment? I know it may seems obiuouvs to you, but it may be not. Just to be sure. Please add here in the comment the links to screenshot showing the shader's node and the particles 's system relevant settings.

Comment: @lemon, you are right

Comment: Not sure bu it looks like there may be a normals issue with your model. Have you tried entering edit mode selecting all faces and recalculate normals with `Ctrl`+`N`?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried what you said and still the same spotty result

Comment: @Carlo I explained my intentions more in depth, any help and tips is much appreciated.

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas, without inspecting the file it's hard to tell what is going on. Make sure in your hair particle settings you checked the option *Use modifier Stack*

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am willing to post the .blend file, how do I do that?

Comment: You may use this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ make sure you strip down your file as simple as possible to to the bare essentials to focus on the problem, and pack any relevant textures and external data

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is the link, it says I need 10 reputation to use more than 2 links -     [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1629" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1629/)

Comment: File added to your question

Comment: Well not sure what you mean, I am not much into particle effects, and I don't have time to look into this in detail right now, but on my computer everything seems to be working quite fine, except for the missing textures. http://i.stack.imgur.com/T1x5v.jpg

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Okay... thanks for trying, I appreciate it. If you can find anything else that would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever it comes to differences with particle systems between preview and final render it almost always has something to do with the subsurf modifier.

1. Always make sure that you have the subsurf modifier enabled in Render and Preview mode when you use "Particle Edit" (cut, comb, etc.). I believe that you had it turned on, when you combed the hair, since it is activated in your file (see image below)
2. Always set the viewport and render settings to the same value when rendering particle systems. If the render setting is lower than the viewport setting (which is the case in your file, see image below) the render process will undo or at least mess up your combed hair.

[image: view differs from render]

Try to set the viewport subdivs to 2 and you'll get the same messed up hair effect you had after rendering.

Set the Render subdivs to 3 and your problem should be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked!! Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you mark my answer as accepted, please? Thx.

Comment: @jacob-lurie Please mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, or at least consider upvoting it if it helped you