# Why do the hair particles go crazy when rendering?

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

I have created hair on a character I am making for animating. I combed the hair and it looked good in the 3D viewport.
[image]
I then rendered it and got this result.
[image]
I then went back to the 3d viewport, and everything looked normal until I right clicked to rotate and then the hair was crazy there as well.
[image]
I loaded a previous save and combed the hair again a few times with the same results every time I rendered it, so I'm thinking it's got something to do with my particle system settings, so here are all my settings for the particle system.
[image]
Any help in resolving my hair problem would be great, THANKS!

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58541/problems-rendering-hair-in-cycles-render/58571#58571 . Look at my answer there.

Comment: That worked, I had the preview at 0 and the render at 3.  if I put the preview at 3 it works fine, however it makes editing everything much slower, is there not a way I can have the preview lower so as to keep everything working faster while editing?  Also, add your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I rearranged the modifiers and put the subserf after the particle system and it works after rendering with the lower number in the preview than the number in the render.

Answer (score 2):

That is probably because your modifiers are in wrong position.
If the mesh with hair particles has a subsurf modifier it should be in the bottom of them.