# How do you fix hair stretching?

Tags: hair

Okay,so I am making a fan model of Ezio Auditore and I added hair.

[image]

But the strange thing is that when I started combing the hair on the base mesh I made of him in MakeHuman,the hair particles started stretching irregularly and i had the Comb tool selected.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on here,please?

Comment: Clarification needed. Did the hair particles started to behave like that right after you imported the model in MakeHuman, or did it start when you start combing? Also consider uploading your .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and adding the given link to your question.

Comment: Have you checked **'use modifier stack'** the particle settings? The modifiers order may be also the key to solve this issue.

Comment: might also be related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58541/problems-rendering-hair-in-cycles-render/58571#58571

Comment: No,that didn't work.

Comment: And maybe the reason is because I imported it with MHX2 hair particles.
That could explain why this is acting so strangely.

Comment: Figured it out,it was the file its self.
I appended the model into a new file and now it's working perfectly,but there is still one more question.
How do you make Ezio's hair shape in blender?